# If I extract something from a stream, does the stream not contain what I extracted anymore?

Tags: c++, stream

If I have code like below and I store `"This"` in `str` first from stream `streem`:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    istringstream streem("This is the content in the stream.");
    string str;
    streem>>str;
    cout<<str; //This will cout "This"
```

If I do `streem>>str` again and `cout<<str` again, this will display `is`.
So does this mean that `"This"` does not exist in the `istringstream` anymore?
`What about`file streams`, because they retain data?

Comment: No. It means you've moved past the word you output to the next position in the stream. You can reset the position to the beginning of the stream to read the word again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is different for different streams  .

The `stringstream` has a memory buffer and an indicator that remembers where you were up to on the reading. So the next read starts where the previous read left off.

File streams work in a similar way, they remember which point of the file they are up to. In both cases you can change position (including resetting to the beginning) using `seekg`.

File streams don't have separate read and write positions, so this same code might behave differently for a file stream . (In fact I think it causes undefined behaviour to read and write without an intervening seek).

Other input streams might not have seekable buffers, e.g. `cin` .